# Deploying Google App Engine and Slim3 code

Tags: google-app-engine

I am developing a GAE app and using Slim3 for persistence. I've created the model and the metamodel. When I try to deploy the app to GAE I get the following error when I run the app.

```
/register
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The meta data of the model(com.principalmvl.lojackmykids.meta.ContactMeta) is not found.
at org.slim3.datastore.DatastoreUtil.createModelMeta(DatastoreUtil.java:801)
at org.slim3.datastore.DatastoreUtil.getModelMeta(DatastoreUtil.java:729)
```

I looked at the lib directory under the WEB-INF directory and I see the generated .CLASS files.

What is the issue? Is there something I need to do on the import or a configuration so that GAE sees this classs?

Comment: we would need some code... how do you declare your model? Hard to say  how to fix the error without knowing what's happening in your code...

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is in the Eclipse project. I recreated a new project and copied all of my servlets and meta data models and it worked. I killed the other project since it seemed to be corrupt.